Nonnegativity of the coefficients of the commuting difference operators of Fomin, Gelfand, and Postnikov evaluated on quantum Schubert polynomials
This post is about quantum Schubert polynomials. Fomin, Gelfand, and Postnikov defined operators in the nil-Hecke ring with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[x,q]$ denoted by $\chi_k$ for $1\leq k\leq n$ for some fixed $n$. Specifically,
$$\chi_k = x_k - \sum_{i<k}q_{ik}\partial^{t_{ik}}+\sum_{k<j}q_{kj}\partial^{t_{kj}}$$
These operators commute and are algebraically independent, and when evaluated on the quantum Schubert polynomials $\mathfrak{S}_u^q(x)$ the "constant term" is the ordinary Schubert polynomial $\mathfrak{S}_u(x)$.
I conjecture that if you write
$$\mathfrak{S}^q_u(\chi_1,\ldots,\chi_n)=\sum_{v\in S_n}p_{uv}(x,q)\partial^v$$
then $p_{uv}(x,q)$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $q$ with nonnegative integer coefficients. I have quite a bit of empirical data to support it (I've tested it up to $n=6$), and I suspect a proof with geometry/topology is possible.
I'm just wondering, is it known whether the coefficients of this operator are polynomials with nonnegative coefficients?
